# Casual employment, hours cut, what should I do?

Tags: employer-relations

My boss and I had a SMS conversation last night:

> Boss: I haven't any work for you tomorrow or Friday. I will let you know
>   over the weekend what the plan is for next week.
>
> Me: Have I done anything wrong? How come the other 2 workers get to
>   keep working?
>
> Boss: No, I'm not replacing you. I am happy with what you
>   do when you're working. You're the hardest worker out of all the
>   employees, but it's the middle of winter and it's about quiet
>
> Me: What am I meant to do about an income? I do have to live and
>   survive, and pay rent!"
>
> Boss: *-NO REPLY-*

As I need to work and earn money, what are my options now in regards to handling my boss?

Comment: Its a hard pill to swallow when you really like the work but thats how it is, I've been through it as well.  Its usually nothing personal. Its all part of being a casual.

Comment: what's your employment situation or agreement ? Do you have a contract ?

Comment: You've not added a location, please do so. In The Netherlands there's such a thing as "de gewoonte", meaning that if you're casually employed (contractually that is) and you "usually" have 10 hours a week, you can require to be paid for 10 hours a week for (I think) 2 months if your hours get cut. Don't quote me on the latter, could be a shorter period. This is to protect people such as yourself as you start living towards an available/"usual" income.

Comment: could you add country tag?

Comment: How long have you been doing casual work? Has this never happened to you before? Have you never seen it happen to anyone else before?

Comment: I'm guessing this is AUS/NZ ("middle of winter"), but I agree a tag would be useful.

Comment: Your boss probably has exactly the same questions you do: *What am I meant to do about an income? I do have to live and survive, and pay rent!*  That doesn't make it easier for you, But it's a reality of seasonal work.

Answer (score 21):

This sounds like you're employed on a casual basis. This is the real risk of the type of employment you are on. You don't know if there will be shifts next week.

It's not your bosses responsibility to deal with your rent, though you did the right thing by letting him know such actions will have a real impact on you.

What you need to do is find a stable job with a salary. I'm empathetic, because sometimes that's very hard to do in certain industries and environments. But if you need a stable income, this is what you have to do. In addition, you can look at a part time role, or even a contract with a bare minimum of hours stipulation.

The other approach is to find alternative employment over winter. Maybe over winter you can work two jobs.

You also should take a brief look over your contract, to make sure you there are no minimum hour stipulations that are not being met.

Answer (score 0):

> what are my options now in regards to handling my boss?

Sounds like there is only one which is to very quickly look for a new job somewhere else and tell your current boss you've quit due to the lowered hours. Depending on the country laws and your contract there is some possibility of being able to claim some money back but given that you haven't added any of this no-one here can really comment.

Regardless you're not getting any more hours from this job and you need the money as you say to live so move on look for another job ASAP.